# How do you negate a $match aggregate in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following query that I need to find the reverse.

```
db.contracts.aggregate([ 
    { $match: { currentBalance: { $gt: 0 }, status: 'open' } }, 
    { $project: { customer_id: 1, lastTransactionDate: 1, currentBalance: 1, status: 1 } }
])
```

I an trying not to use

```
$or: [ currentBalance: { $ne: 0 }, status: { $ne: 'open' } ]
```

What I would really like is to use `$not: [ condition ]` as I will have more difficult aggregations to write. However I cannot find the right syntax. Any help appreciated. I am using mongodb 3.0.7

Comment: Please put some effort into properly tabbing your queries next time. They are super hard to read otherwise

Comment: Why are you trying not to use `$ne`? Is your condition going to be an array? If so, use `$nin` https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/

Comment: See also: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/not/

Comment: This was just an example of a query I needed today. I know that in the future I will encounter much more difficult queries to negate and I know by experience that sometimes expressing a query straightforward and then checking for its opposite is easier and faster that reversing the truth of each operator and operand. So if I want to $notmatch how would I write it in mongo query?

Answer (score 17):

I think this is essentially what you mean (apologies if $not)

```
db.contracts.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      currentBalance: { $not: { $gt: 0 } },
      status: { $not: { $eq: 'open' } },
    },
  },

  {
    $project: {
      customer_id: 1,
      lastTransactionDate: 1,
      currentBalance: 1,
      status: 1
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
db.contracts.aggregate([ 
    { $match: { 
         currentBalance: 0, 
         status: { 
             $not: { 
                 $regex: 'open' 
             }
         }
     }
   }, 
   { $project: {
         customer_id: 1, 
         lastTransactionDate: 1, 
         currentBalance: 1, 
         status: 1 
     }
   }
])
```